# Limit the user input from 0 to 100 AND limit the user input to only numbers

Tags: python

Fresh Python learner here,
I've been pulling my hair out to find out how to fix this.

The program below only shows error like "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'" if user input is not a number. Is there a way to fix this?
I also want to limit the user input from 0 to 100.

---

```
print("please enter your 5 marks")

#read 5 inputs
mark1 = int(input("enter mark 1: "))
mark2 = int(input("enter mark 2: "))
mark3 = int(input("enter mark 3: "))
mark4 = int(input("enter mark 4: "))
mark5 = int(input("enter mark 5: "))

#create array/list with five marks
marks = [mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5]

#print the array/list
print(marks)

#calculate the sum and average
sumOfMarks = sum(marks)
averageOfMarks = sum(marks)/5

#display results
print("The sum of your marks is: "+str(sumOfMarks))
print("The average of your marks is: "+str(averageOfMarks))
```

---

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags to your question, this has nothing to do with java

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle those errors learn the try catch , they are made to catch multiple errors such as the one you are looking for

here is an example that may help you fix your code

copy and past it a new page , run it and analyse it then try to implement it in your code

try:

```
  num = int(input("Enter an number: "))
  print("num:", num)
except ValueError:
    print(" input integer only...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own `input` function that will keep prompting until a valid number between 0 and 100 is given:

```
def num_input(prompt):
  s = input(prompt)
  while True:
    try:
      s = int(s)
      if s not in range(101):
        s = input("That number is not between 0 and 100. Please try again: ")
      else:
        break
    except:
      s = input("That is not a valid number. Please try again: ")
  return s

mark1 = num_input("enter mark 1: ")
mark2 = num_input("enter mark 2: ")
mark3 = num_input("enter mark 3: ")
mark4 = num_input("enter mark 4: ")
mark5 = num_input("enter mark 5: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

```
print("please enter your 5 marks")

num = 5
marks = []
for i in range(num):
    aa = int(input("enter mark"+str(i)+":"))
    try:
        if 1 <= aa <= 100:
            marks.append(aa)
        else:
            print("Input is out of range!")
    except:
        print('Input is not valid!')

print(marks)

#calculate the sum and average
sumOfMarks = sum(marks)
averageOfMarks = sum(marks)/5

#display results
print("The sum of your marks is: "+str(sumOfMarks))
print("The average of your marks is: "+str(averageOfMarks))
```